# MADE.UI.Controls.DropDownList all items dedault to true(selected)...?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, user-interface, uwp

https://made-apps.github.io/MADE.NET/articles/features/ui-controls-dropdownlist.html

Hi, i try to use MADE.UI.Controls.DropDownList is there a way to put all items dedault to true(selected)...?

Is there a workaround to use dis customcontrol with the selectorItem object?

Comment: Hello, I think you should maybe copy your title into your post, and make your title more like a title.

Comment: then u send the link to someone who can help me! ;D